# Getting the version tag for various inputs

Tags: python

INPUT:-

```
tag#1INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.00.00.042.1
tag#2INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.00.00.042.1
tag#3INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.00.042.1
tag#4INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.c2.00.00.042.1
tag#5INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.c2.00.00.042
```

CODE:-

Hi,

I have the following code which works for tag#1 in the INPUT shown above but fails for other tags,output should be "042" for all the inputs..can anyone suggest how to fix this?

```
import re
comments = [{u'timestamp': 1403046914, u'message': u'Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, but someone else must approve\n\nThis patchset has been processed by the Gator.', u'reviewer': {u'username': u'gator', u'name': u'Gator Service Account', u'email': u'gator@localhost'}}, {u'timestamp': 1403051700, u'message': u'Patch Set 1: Developer Build and Test Successful\n\nINCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.00.00.042.1\n\nhttp://qwiki.company.com/div_wcnss/SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.c2.00.00.042.1', u'reviewer': {u'username': u'username', u'name': u'user name2 ', u'email': u'username@div.company.com'}}, {u'timestamp': 1403052176, u'message': u'Patch Set 1: Looks good to me, approved\n\n', u'reviewer': {u'username': u'username2', u'name': u'user full name', u'email': u'username2@div.company.com'}}]

matchobj = re.search(r"INCLUDED IN DATABUILD:\s+\S+?\.(?:\d+\.){5}(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?", str(comments))
print matchobj

build = matchobj.group(1)
print build

chunks = build.split('.')
print chunks

last_one = chunks[-1]
print last_one
```

Comment: Only `tag1` has seven numbers separated with dot and this part `(?:\d+\.){5}(\d+)(?:\.\d+)` expects seven numbers.

Comment: @furas - can we change the regex to be generic to match all the tags shown in input

Comment: There is problem with 042 - sometimes it is last number, sometimes it is not. It can be fourth/fifth/sixth number from the beginning. There is no one clear rule. How do you recognize that number ? I see only one rule - 3 digits. has this number always 3 digits ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for first 3-digits number after `INCLUDE` then you can use

```
import re

examples = [
    'tag#1INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.00.00.041.1 - next 3-digits numer 007',
    'tag#2INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.00.00.052.1 - next 3-digits numer 007',
    'tag#3INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.00.042.1 - next 3-digits numer 007',
    'tag#4INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.c2.00.00.142.1 - next 3-digits numer 007',
    'tag#5INCLUDED IN DATABUILD: SU_TAG_PL_DATA.LA.3.6.1.c2.00.00.002 - next 3-digits numer 007'
]

for x in examples:
    r = re.search(r'INCLUDED IN DATABUILD.*?(\d{3})', x)
    print( r.group(1) )
```

In example I replaced `042` with different numbers to better see results.

```
041
052
042
142
002
```

Comment: how can I change it look for first 3-digit or 4-digit number?

Comment: Use `{3,4}` in `r'INCLUDED IN DATABUILD.*?(\d{3,4})'`